# My program works in Python shell but doesn't recognize my input when it runs in cmd.exe

Tags: python, string, input, exe

Hey I'm totally new at this and not sure why I'm even trying to run my code in the cmd.exe...

But, when I run my script in there it doesn't recognize when I type in my correct password for the input. It works fine when I run it in the python shell though.

Any answers or help pointing my in the right direction of what I need to learn would be great.

```
secret_info=["Whatmough","Graham","NOOB"]
password="1234"
tries=0
locked = 1

def cracker():
    attempt=input("Type your Password: ")

    return attempt

def checker():
    global locked, tries
    if cracker() == password:
         locked = 0
    else:
        tries = tries + 1


while 3 > tries and locked==1:
    checker()
    if locked == 0:
        print(secret_info)
    if tries == 3:
        secret_info=0
        print("Self Distructed! Your secret info is now:", secret_info)
```

Comment: How are you running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `cmd`  adds a carriage return(`'\r'`) to the input string.

You can see that `"\r"` if you try to print `repr(attempt)`.

To remove that carriage return you can use `str.strip()` or `str.rstrip("\r")`.

```
attempt = input("Type your Password: ").rstrip("\r")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It's crashing now though.  Is there something else that I would have to change for it to work in cmd?